# import table data to another database in another computer in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, data-import

i have generated the script and created the schema in my computer. now how can i get the tables data? i dont have enough access in the remote database to copy it. 
Can it be done using sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your tables and everything setup, you can do a number of things:

- create some SQL scripts with INSERT statements
- create an app that uses something like SqlBulkCopy to insert data
- use SQL Server Integration Services to import data
- plenty of other ways.....

You need to ask a bit more focused - this question cannot really be answered.....

**Update:**
For option #1, you need to do these steps:

- somehow create your INSERT scripts from your local database - you can do this manually, or use some of the available tools ([SQL Data Dumper](http://www.ruizata.com/), [Table Scripter](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/seanprice/archive/2007/08/28/data-scripter-add-in-for-management-studio.aspx), or use the built-in functionality of [SQL Server Mgmt Studio](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-script-data-with-generate-script-wizard.aspx)) out there
- transfer those *.sql script files to your hoster (via FTP, via a web portal upload - whatever)
- execute those *.sql scripts on your remote hosting environment - either you have access to some form of a SQL Server management tool (either Mgmt Studio or `sqlcmd` on the command line), or your hoster provides some form of a web-based tool to load and execute those scripts (which depends on your hoster and varies quite a bit between hosters)

Check out those additional blog posts by Scott Guthrie on the topic:

- [Recipe: Deploying a SQL Database to a Remote Hosting Environment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/22/recipe-deploying-a-sql-database-to-a-remote-hosting-environment-part-1.aspx)
- [Tip/Trick: How to upload a .SQL file to a Hoster and Execute it to Deploy a SQL Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/01/11/tip-trick-how-to-upload-a-sql-file-to-a-hoster-and-execute-it-to-deploy-a-sql-database.aspx)

Comment: can you explain the first way? how can i run these insert statements because i tried to do that from the local db selecting from the remote one, previously executed the sp_addlinkedserver and i couldnt because i dont have a connection that has access on both servers and db.